# Search/Replace/Delete Jekyll YAML Front Matter Category Tags

Tags: python, ruby, yaml, jekyll

I've inherited a Jekyll website and I'm coming from a .NET world so it's a learning curve for me.

This Jekyll site takes forever to build and I think it is because there are literally thousands of category tags that require those pages to be removed.  I'm able to get a list of all the categories and created a CSV that I'd like to loop through and figure out if a category tag is still needed.  The structure of the CSV is:

```
old_tag,new_tag
```

Clearly I'd like to update the tags based on those (e.g. make all C#, C-Sharp, C # and C Sharp categories just C-Sharp).  But, I'd also like to delete some where the old tag field exists and the new one is blank:

```
old_tag,new_tag
C#, C-Sharp
C Sharp, C-Sharp
Crazy, 
C #, C-Sharp
```

Using Ruby or Python I'd like to figure out how to loop through over 4000 markdown files and use the CSV to conditionally update each one.  The database person in me just can't think how this would work with flat files.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend starting with a Hash, using it like a translation table. Hash lookups are very fast, and can organize your tags and their replacements nicely.

```
hash = {
  # old_tag => new_tag
  'C#'      => 'C-Sharp',
  'C Sharp' => 'C-Sharp',
  'Crazy'   => '',
  'C #'     => 'C-Sharp',
}
```

You can see there's a lot of redundancy in the values, which could be fixed by reversing the hash, which reduces it nicely:

```
hash = {
  # new_tag => old_tag
  'C-Sharp' => ['C#', 'C Sharp', 'C #'],
}
```

`'Crazy'` is an outlier, but we will deal with that.

Ruby's `String.gsub` has a nice, but little used feature, where we can pass it a regular expression, and a hash, and it'll replace all regex matches with the equivalent value in the hash. We can build that regex easily:

```
regex = /(?:#{ Regexp.union(hash.keys).source })/
=> /(?:C\-Sharp)/
```

Now, you're probably saying, "but wait, I have a lot more tags to find!", and, because of the way the hash is built, they're hidden in the values. To remedy that, we'll reverse the hash's keys and values, exploding the value arrays into their individual elements:

```
reversed_hash = Hash[hash.flat_map{ |k,v| v.map{ |i| [i,k] } }]
=> {
         "C#" => "C-Sharp",
    "C Sharp" => "C-Sharp",
        "C #" => "C-Sharp",
}
```

Adding in `'Crazy'` is easy, by merging a second hash of the "special cases":

```
special_cases = {
  'Crazy' => ''
}

reversed_hash = Hash[hash.flat_map{ |k,v| v.map{ |i| [i,k] } }].merge(special_cases)
=> {
         "C#" => "C-Sharp",
    "C Sharp" => "C-Sharp",
        "C #" => "C-Sharp",
      "Crazy" => ""
}
```

Using that with the regex buildin' code:

```
regex = /(?:#{ Regexp.union(reversed_hash.keys).source })/
=> /(?:C\#|C\ Sharp|C\ \#|Crazy)/
```

That will find the tags using a auto-generated regex. If it needs to be case-insensitive, use:

```
regex = /(?:#{ Regexp.union(reversed_hash.keys).source })/i
```

Creating some text to test against:

```
text =<<EOT
This is "#C#"
This is "C Sharp"
This is "C #"
This is "Crazy"
EOT
=> "This is \"#C#\"\nThis is \"C Sharp\"\nThis is \"C #\"\nThis is \"Crazy\"\n"
```

And testing the `gsub`:

```
puts text.gsub(regex, reversed_hash)
```

Which outputs:

```
This is "#C-Sharp"
This is "#C-Sharp"
This is "#C-Sharp"
This is "#"
```

Now, I'm not a big fan of slurping big files into memory, because that doesn't scale well. Today's machines usually have many GB of memory, but I see files that still exceed the RAM in a machine. So, instead of using a `File.read` to load the file, then a single `gsub` to process it, I recommend using `File.foreach`. Using that changes the code.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
file_to_read = '/path/to/file/to/read'
File.open(file_to_read + '.new', 'w') do |fo|
  File.foreach(file_to_read) do |li|
    fo.puts li.gsub(regex, reversed_hash)
  end
end

File.rename(file_to_read, file_to_read + '.bak')
File.rename(file_to_read + '.new', file_to_read)
```

This will create a .bak version of each file processed, so if something goes wrong you have a fall-back, which is always a good practice.

---

Edit: I forgot about the CSV file:

You can read/create one easily with Ruby using the CSV module, however I'd go with a YAML file because it allows you to easily create your hash layout in a file that is easy to edit by hand, or generate from a file.

---

Edit: More about CSV, YAML and generating one from the other

Here's how to read the CSV and convert it into the recommended hash format:

```
require 'csv'

text = <<EOT
C#, C-Sharp
C Sharp, C-Sharp
Crazy,
C #, C-Sharp
EOT

hash = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = [] }
special_cases = []
CSV.parse(text) do |k,v|
  (
    (v.nil? || v.strip.empty?) ? special_cases : hash[v.strip]
  ) << k.strip
end
```

Picking up from before:

```
reversed_hash = Hash[hash.flat_map{ |k,v| v.map{ |i| [i,k] } }].merge(Hash[special_cases.map { |k| [k, ''] }])
puts reversed_hash
# => {"C#"=>"C-Sharp", "C Sharp"=>"C-Sharp", "C #"=>"C-Sharp", "Crazy"=>""}
```

To convert the CSV file to something more editable and useful, use the above code to create `hash` and `special_cases`, then:

```
require 'yaml'

puts ({
  'hash' => hash,
 'special_cases' => special_cases
}).to_yaml
```

Which looks like:

```
---
hash:
  C-Sharp:
  - C#
  - C Sharp
  - ! 'C #'
special_cases:
- Crazy
```

The rest you can figure out from the YAML docs.

Comment: Cool trick with the second argument to `#gsub`. Can you use `Hash#invert` to get your `reversed_hash`? `{1 => :a, 2 => :b}.invert # => {:a=>1, :b=>2}`.

Comment: `invert` works for hashes with simple `'key' => 'value'` combinations, but this particular hash has arrays of values. While Ruby allows an array as a key, because hash accepts an object for the key, the code needs each element of the value to be turned into its own key.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible approach; not sure how well it will work for large amounts of data:

```
require "stringio"
require "csv"

class MarkdownTidy
  def initialize(rules)
    @csv = CSV.new(rules.is_a?(IO) ? rules : StringIO.new(rules))
    @from_to = {}.tap do |hsh|
      @csv.each do |from, to|
        re = Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(from.strip))
        hsh[re] = to.strip
      end
    end
  end

  def tidy(str)
    cpy = str.dup
    @from_to.each do |re, canonical|
      cpy.gsub! re, canonical
    end
    cpy
  end
end

csv = <<-TEXT
C#, C-Sharp
C Sharp, C-Sharp
Crazy, 
C #, C-Sharp
TEXT

markdown = <<-TEXT
C# some text C # some text Crazy
C#, C Sharp
TEXT

mt = MarkdownTidy.new(csv)
[markdown].each do |str|
  puts mt.tidy(markdown)
end
```

The idea is that you would replace the loop at the very end with one that opens up the files, reads them and then saves them back to disk.